# Connection string to connect to MySql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I am trying to connect MySql database to my forms. I got the connection string by right clicking on my database connection and going to properties.

```
connection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=island_dealership;"+
       "persistsecurityinfo=True;allowuservariables=True";
```

Below is image of an error and complete code.

[image]

car.cs class: here I'm trying to connect to the database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace DatabaseProject
{
    public partial class Car : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlConnection cmd;
        public Car()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=island_dealership;persistsecurityinfo=True;allowuservariables=True";//Connection String....
                connection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connected to MySql database");
            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection failed Due to " + e1.ToString());
            }

        }

        private void submitCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're not specifying a password.  [http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: The connection string is missing the password. You have to add the password. It should be some thing like this "data source=ServerName\InstanceName;initial catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=SQLLoginName;Password=SQLLoginPassword;

Comment: Don't use the `root` user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably want to know the password ;) Your message box says so:

> using password: NO... Access Denied...

Like so:

```
server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=YOURPASSWORDHERE;database=YOURDATABASENAMEHERE;
```

Comment: I am using `static string connstring = @"server=my.live.ip;userid=user;password=123;database=db_name;port=3306";`

but still I am getting `Authentication to host 'my.live.ip' for user 'user' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'user'@'202.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: NO)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the code here below or refer to this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/43438/connect-c-to-mysql)

```
private MySqlConnection connection;
private string server;
private string database;
private string uid;
private string password;

//Constructor
public DBConnect()
{
    Initialize();
}

//Initialize values
private void Initialize()
{
    server = "localhost";
    database = "connectcsharptomysql";
    uid = "username";
    password = "password";
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}

//open connection to database
private bool OpenConnection()
{
}

//Close connection
private bool CloseConnection()
{
}

//Insert statement
public void Insert()
{
}

//Update statement
public void Update()
{
}

//Delete statement
public void Delete()
{
}

//Select statement
public List <string> [] Select()
{
}

//Count statement
public int Count()
{
}

//Backup
public void Backup()
{
}

//Restore
public void Restore()
{
}
```